# Copy string function not working in C

Tags: c, string, copy, cstring

Ok, I have a function to check if a number is a palindrome (it is not completed yet) which calls a function called `copystring()`.

If I have

```
putchar(*destination)
```

Within the `copystring()` function loop, it outputs the destination string as it should.
However, the original string within the `is_palindrome` function is not being edited. It remains blank.  Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
int is_palindrome(int num)
{
    char buffer[30];
    char reversebuffer[30];
    sprintf(buffer, "%d", num);

    copystring(reversebuffer, buffer);
    reversestring(reversebuffer, strlen(reversebuffer));
}

void copystring(char *destination, char *source)
{
    while (*source){
        *destination = *source;
        ++source;
        ++destination;

    }
    *destination = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the standard `strcpy()`?

Comment: Post the source for `reversestring()` or make absolutely sure that the bug isn't in that function. `copystring()` works fine for me.

Comment: Which _original string_ are you referring to? `buffer` or `reversebuffer`? What makes you think it's blank? Show your code that demonstrates this.

Comment: buffer is the original, i am trying to copy its contents into reverse buffer. printf() on reversebuffer immediately after calling copystring() gives no output

Comment: It is working for me http://codepad.org/wGYNSjVL

Comment: yes it was working for me at one point in another program but that was called directly from main.  I tried using strcpy() instead, which works fine.  However, as soon as I call copystring() instead it does not work

Comment: Did you try to run your program with a debugger ? I don't see any problems in your copystring function.

Comment: @MichaelWalz No, I'm fairly new to programming. I have gdb installed on my system but don't know how to use it.

Comment: Well, then it's about time to start learning how to use gdb. It's very powerful and it will help you greatly to understand what's happening in the software you write.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the issue, it works for me fine.
Anyway, you are working too hard for it. It would be much more efficient to write something like:

```
bool is_palindrome2(int num)
{
    char buffer[30];
    sprintf_s(buffer, "%d", num);
    int length = strlen(buffer);

    for(int i=0; i < length/2 ; i++)
    {
        if(buffer[i] != buffer[length - i - 1])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the end of copy string() function both destination and source pointers are pointing to '\0' character, so if call putchar(*destination) or putchar(*source), they will print blank.

Comment: putchar() was within the loop immediately after *destination = *source